# Redirect a sub-domain to a folder and hide the folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following domain pmartins.pt, and I added the following sub-domain euromilhoes.pmartins.pt . I needed to point the sub-domain to pmartins.pt/euromilhoes/public and I used the following in the .htaccess

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /euromilhoes/public [L]`

This works fine but I would like to hide the public folder from the URL. So now I have this http://pmartins.pt/euromilhoes/public/, and I would like it to be http://pmartins.pt/euromilhoes/

Can I do it via .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from root to subfolder ,you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
#exclude existent dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#exclude existent files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rewrite any other request to /publice
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thx, but this does not seem to achieve what I need. When I load this .htaccess to the root of my sub-domain, and I access it, http://euromilhoes.pmartins.pt I get the index list of files/folders